# What distribution would lead to this highly peaked and skewed density plot?

Tags: r, distributions

The density of my data set was plotted in R as follows.

[image]

What kind of distribution would fit this data?

As I am not experienced to tell by visualization, I can only guess it is not normally distributed.  I shall test it with R: some guidance as a starting point is highly desirable.

Comment: Does it has discrete or continuous values?

Comment: Does your data has negative values?

Comment: @Dimitrij I doubt it - the default for `density` in R assumes unbounded data hence the bleeding of density below zero.

Comment: @Gavin, I doubt it myself, it looks like being from exponential or Gamma distribution, but more info would on the data source would be nice to know.

Comment: @Dmitrij, The values itself has no negative data.  I know most of the model need to have negative data.  Since I am only interested in the trend, not absolute value.  I scale all values by a constant mean and a constant std dev.  Then, I transformed all data using the equation of calculating Z-score, to make the number has both positive and negative value before fitting.  Is it a reasonable approach?

Comment: @Gavin  Could you mind to comment on the z-score approach in my reply to Dmitrij?

Comment: @mdq  It is about hard to define.  One of my dataset has 545490 datapoints, and most of them has dec. place numbers.  So, I suspect I should define it as continuous.  Do you think it is reasonable to define it as continuous?

Comment: @evdstat, it is still not clear what kind of a data it is. For example if it is some time between two events, then http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution seems relevant (or some Gamma or Weibull for more flexible density fit). Note, that the choice is somewhat application dependent, in survival analysis for instance Weibull is common, though I prefer Gamma family, both include exponential as a separate case.

Comment: @evdstat: This looks to me like it's coming from a distribution with heavy tails, such as a Frechet distribution or an inverse gamma distribution or mayby a Pareto distribution. I'd be interested in knowing more about the source of these data. Marketing?

Comment: Here's an old answer:

http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8662/need-help-identifying-a-distribution-by-its-histogram/8674#8674

Comment: Reminds me of a Weibull distribution I fitted with some "weird" parameters.

Answer (score 4):

It looks rather like an exponential distribution (assuming that the bit below 0 is an artifact of smoothing in the density estimation).

I would look at a qqplot.  In R, if `x` contains your data:

```
n <- length(x)
qqplot(x, qexp( (1:n - 0.5)/n ) )
```

Note that in the use of `density()` for the non-negative case, it is best to use `from=0` since you know the density is 0 below 0.

```
plot(density(x, from=0))
```

I think also that, if $X$ follows an exponential distribution, then $e^{-X/\mu_X}$ should follow a uniform distribution, so the following could be a reasonable diagnostic:

```
hist(exp(-x/mean(x)), breaks=2*sqrt(length(x)))
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not usually possible to identify a distribution from looking at a histogram like this.

As a start, **plot the density on a log scale**:

[image: Log density plot]

The tail of this density (from around 40 onward) is close to linear, showing it is close to exponential.  That's part of the characterization.  To go further, *compare* the density to this characterization by forming the residuals (on a log scale, effectively taking the *ratio* of the density to an exponential curve):

[image: Residuals]

Clearly this density is *not* exponential: for small values it is almost four times greater than the exponential fit to the tail would indicate.  We must go further with the characterization.

**We seek to characterize the residuals as simply as possible:** this means in terms of longish straight segments or parabolic sections.  (On this log scale, a straight segment is an exponential trend, whereas a parabolic section looks like a piece of a *Normal* distribution.)  Evidently there are two parabolic-like sections: a sharp peaked one centered near 1 and a shallow, broad one centered near 25-30.  The first would correspond to a healthy part of a truncated Normal distribution with small standard deviation (around 5-6) whereas the second would correspond to most of a Normal distribution with a larger standard deviation (around 10 perhaps).  This indicates the density is not going to be adequately described by a simple mathematical formula, such as a Gamma or Weibull, but perhaps it can be decomposed into a *mixture* of two or three components.  Look for each of those components to have some meaning: could these data indeed involve some combination of phenomena tending to occur near 1, near 25, and out beyond 40?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, as others have, that the small blip below zero is an artifact of a density smoothing process, rather than a small amount of negative data, your distribution *looks* like an exponential distribution.

I'd start with either a exponential distribution, or the slightly more flexible Weibull distribution, and see if either one of those seems to fit well. Those two are a decent balance between difficulty to implement, visualize, etc. and having a decent likelihood of fitting your data.

Answer (score 1):

This is a long-tail distribution.
GB2 (Generalized beta of second kind) with four parameters has a good flexibility for this kind of data.
It's in package `GB2`.